# Move to a new page after entering a character in input textbox holding the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement in my webpage something similar to google search page. The link http://www.google.com shows the search field at the middle of the page and on typing a character it moves to the top of the page holding the input entered.

Would be great if someone can demonstrate to achieve this using jquery/javascript or html

Comment: Right, so you go to google page and right click and see source, for your search you can use `autocomplete` anyhoo; don't try to make your own searching algorithm though `:)` you might need huge infra for it not to mention grid stuff with you new mapreduce algorithm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put up a small script for you, to get an idea. Work on it and read [jquery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) in the course of this. This should get you started, http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/uZ8xv/2/

btw, Gogole doesn't redirect you on Instant search. t moves the divs around, and this example is a very tiny prototype to demonstrate the same.

```
<div class="block">
    <input id="ip" type="text" />
    <div class="res">NULL</div>
</div>  

div {
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
  top:100px;
}​
```

​

```
var d = false;

$("#ip").keyup(function(){
    if(d ==false){
    $(".block").animate({"top": "-=50px"});
        d= true;
    }
    var v =$(this).val();
    $(".res").html("Search results for " + v );
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Useing `keypress` and `appendTo`

```
<div style="height:30px;" id="divMain">
    Move entire form below here on search
</div>
<br />
<div style="height:90px;" id="divOther">
<br />Some text...
<form id="frmSubmit">  
  Search: <input type="text" id="txtSearch" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#txtSearch").keypress(function() {
    $("#frmSubmit").appendTo("#divMain");
    $('#txtSearch').focus();
});​
```

Final:

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/maSFE/2/)